# Difference when using [Some.Object] to create an object in powershell

Tags: object, powershell, syntax

What is the difference between creating an object this way:

```
$form.Size = New-Object [System.Drawing.Size] 250, 250
```

and this way:

```
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 250, 250
```

The first one fails, but the second one does not.  Are the brackets only to be used when calling static values from an object?

Comment: Good question for those who are unfamiliar with PowerShell syntax. Upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you put square brackets around the .NET type name, you get a reference to the .NET type itself. `New-Object` is expecting a string representation of the .NET type that you're instantiating, which gets mapped to the `-TypeName` parameter.

You use the square brackets to reference a .NET type, for example, if you are calling a static method on a class.

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

The help on New-Object says:

```
Synopsis
    Creates an instance of a Microsoft .NET Framework or COM object.

Syntax
    New-Object [-TypeName] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>] [-Property <IDictionary>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Note that the argument for Typename is string.  When you include the square bracktets, it's looking for a typename that literally contains square brackets.